# Oracle Spatial - How to calculate the point of intersection of 2 line geometries

Tags: oracle-spatial

How to calculate the point of intersection of 2 line geometries.

Answer (score 3):

sdo_relate or sdo_intersection?
It has been a while since I have used spatial.
This might be a place to start.
[otn spatial forum](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=9245322�)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this?

with sdo_anyinteract

http://bokk74.blog.kataweb.it/2015/11/19/calcolo-percentuale-intersezione-geometrie-in-oracle/